# Facing WHMCS SSL Redirect Loop When Forcing SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, web-hosting, whmcs

Whenever I try to force **https://** on whmcs, it goes in redirect loop, I have tried every method on the internet, every google link turned purple but just cant find the solution, so now I'm here asking for help....

I am using latest whmcs version.

I know ssl is installed correctly because it works fine when I type it in manually

I have tried setting the main whmcs url as **https://** but still get stuck with a redirect loop

I have also tried using .htaccess code below to do this but still redirect loop...

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have even tried both at the same time but no luck....

I hope I can find my solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These rules is working for me, notice the second line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Also, in Setup > General Settings, use https for WHMCS System URL.